# How to manipulate the registration process in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I've just started playing with meteor.  It looks awesome. I want to customise the registration process from accounts-ui to:

1. Make users enter additional data when registering (their birthdate)
2. After they register show them another modal/page for them to enter a bit more data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

or you should use "meteor add accounts-password" then you can use Accounts.api to make your own registration process.

http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser

make your form as your need, then use any way to pass form data to

```
Accounts.createUser(options, [callback])
```

something like

```
var options = {
    username: $('#input-username').val(),
    password: $('#input-password').val(),
    profiles: {
        birthday: $('#input-birthday').val
    }
};
Accounts.createUser(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Accounts.createUser you can store additional data under profile like this.

```
Meteor.methods({
'createUser': function(firstname, lastname, username, twitter, email, password, role){
    Accounts.createUser({

        email: email,
        password: password,
        username: username,
        profile: {
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            twitter: twitter,
            birthdate: birthdate
        }
    }); 
},
```

If you want a second form you can route the user to it.

```
Template.registerUser.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var firstname = event.target.firstnam.value;
        ...

        Meteor.call('createUser', clubName, capacity, description, homepage);
        Router.go('userInfoStep2');
    }
});
```

I guess you also can do the redirect in the routfile.

This is a simple solution and does not take care of cases when the user breaks the registration process in the middle. But maybe someone else can help with that?